# ML .NET can't create ".mbconfig"-File

Tags: .net, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

I'm trying to get in touch with ML .NET, but I can't add a ".mbconfig"-File to a existing Project. The "Machine Learning Model..." Menu-Context is available, but not the ".mbconfig"-File (see Picture for Menu-Context)[image]

See Video-Link for verifying, that there is no ".mbconfig"-File to choose from: https://files.fm/u/ysg5u72px

Currently I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview (17.4.0 Preview 1.0).
ML Builder was installed via Visual Studio, so it should be the most recent Version (See Picture)[image: ML Builder installed]

The following Pictures are showing you, what it should look like, when I'm clicking on "Machine learning Model..."
**First possible Outcome**:  [image: Machine Learning Modell Dialog by microsoft]

**Second possible Outcome**:  [image: Another ML Builder perspective]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the Solution on my own.
I had to activate the "**ML.NET Model Builder 2022**" within "**Extensions**" >> "**Installed**" >> Click on the "**activate**" Button which appears after you clicked on the Extension "**ML.NET Model Builder 2022**".

Yeah, that was the issue… It is working now, because it is now activated :x